# Limit of sequence of piece-wise function

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence of functions $f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$f_{n}(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n\leq x \leq n + 1 \\ 
0 & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}$

What is $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)$?

When I think about $f_{n}$ graphically, I see that $f_{n}(x) = 1$ and $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

For $x = 1$, $f_{n}([0, 2]) = 1$, and $f_{n} = 0$ everywhere else.

For $x = 2$, $f_{n}([1, 3]) = 1$, and $f_{n} = 0$ everywhere else.

For $x = 3$, $f_{n}([2, 4]) = 1$, and $f_{n} = 0$ everywhere else.

...and so forth. So eventually $f_{n}(x) = 1$ and $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Which would suggest that the limit does not exist, right? But the next part of the question asks if $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, so I assume $f(x)$ does exist...?

Comment: For a fixed $x$, $f_n(x)=0$ for $n$ large enough. Hence the limit is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: So in this case we're not looking at every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, just any fixed $x$?

Comment: Yes, you are searching for the so called pointwise limit. You fix x, and look for the limit of $f_n(x)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. If such limit exists, you denote it by f(x).

Comment: @Adrian: You ARE looking at every $x\in R$! There is no difference between every $x$ and any fixed $x$. Check the statment closely: you have to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$. What does it mean? Particularly, the statement does not ask to consider $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(n)$. Btw, what do you mean with $f_n([0,2])=1?$